# Draw text in Racket

Tags: racket

I need to draws a slide, showing only its title and shown part on a large background of a fixed size. Should I use the (text " " 25 "black") or just use the slide. Beside text function, is there other function can draw text?

```
(define SLIDE-1-LOS
  (cons "Designing programs to solve problems"
        (cons "Building good habits for developing large systems with a team"
              (cons "CS: fundamental ideas, thinking" '()))))

(define SLIDE-2-LOS
  (cons "Effectively using computers as tools"
        (cons "Breaking down problems" '())))

(define SLIDE-3-LOS
  (cons "Easy to start"
        (cons "Informative feedback"
              (cons "Functional programming is a useful paradigm" '()))))
(define-struct slide [title shown hidden])
(define SLIDE-1
  (make-slide
   "What is Fundies 1 About?"
   '() SLIDE-1-LOS))

(define SLIDE-1-NEXT
  (make-slide
   "What is Fundies 1 About?"
   (cons "Designing programs to solve problems" '())
   (cons "Building good habits for developing large systems with a team"
         (cons "CS: fundamental ideas, thinking" '()))))

(define SLIDE-1-NEXT-NEXT
  (make-slide
   "What is Fundies 1 About?"
   (cons "Designing programs to solve problems"
         (cons "Building good habits for developing large systems with a team" '()))
   (cons "CS: fundamental ideas, thinking" '())))

(define SLIDE-1-DONE
  (make-slide "What is Fundies 1 About?"
              SLIDE-1-LOS '()))
(define bg(square 400 "solid" "white"))
(define (draw-slide s)
  (place-image
   overlay
           ;what should I put in between this
   bg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student studying HtDP:

1. You should follow the design recipe. In particular, what is the template for a function taking a slide?
2. Yes, `text` seems like a reasonable way of turning a string into an image.
3. `place-image` is one way of combining images, but it isn't the only one. What other functions are available for combining images?
4. You should not post homework solutions on stackoverflow.

---

If you are not a student:

You can use the [Slideshow](https://docs.racket-lang.org/slideshow/index.html) language/library in Racket to design slide presentations.